# Find element's position in browser scroll

Tags: javascript, html

i need some help about finding elements position.
im working on an e-book reader, also its all Html with css.
All html sectioned page by page, and i have to find an element like this

`<span name="Note" style="background-color:rgb(255,255,204)">Example</span>`

Everyone suggests code like this;

```
function position(elem) {
    var left = 0,
        top = 0;

    do {
        left += elem.offsetLeft;
        top += elem.offsetTop;
    } while ( elem = elem.offsetParent );

    return [ left, top ];
}position(document.getElementsByName('Note')[0]);
```

but it does not work for me; I need element's real position in scroll with JavaScript.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by _"it does not work for me; I need element's real position in scroll with JavaScript."_. What does not work? (Are you getting error messages, or bad values?) What do you mean by the "real position in scroll"? What are you trying to use this value for?

Comment: its not working when i change the html's body font-face, when i try to scroll returned value, it's going another place.

Comment: Have you tried simply `myNote.scrollIntoView()`?

Comment: Scroll position at Y axis; in javascript code window.scrollY.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

```
var note = document.getElementsByName('Note')[0];
var screenPosition = note.getBoundingClientRect();
```

The ClientRect returned by [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getBoundingClientRect) has values for `.top`, `.left`, `.right`, `.bottom`, `.width`, and `.height`.

These are pixel positions on the visible window; as you scroll the page the `.top` and `.bottom` values will change, and may even become negative as the item scrolls off the top of the view.

Note that—unlike the solution accumulating `offsetLeft`/`offsetTop`—this solution properly accounts for borders and padding on the `body` and `html` elements in all browsers (Firefox).

See this test case: http://jsfiddle.net/QxYDe/4/ (scroll the page and watch the values change).

*Also [supported by Internet Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536433(v=vs.85).aspx).*

Comment: its good, but not work for me.. it returns position in screen, not for scroll position :/

Comment: @relower You need to explain what you mean by this. See [this test page](http://jsfiddle.net/QxYDe/1/).

Comment: @relower As I specifically mentioned, it will return negative values if the item is off the top of the window. This seems to be what you are asking for. If you don't want the scrolling to be taken into account, then your original code works. If you do not want the body scrolling to be taken into account, but do want scrolling for other elements accounted for, then you may wish to add `document.body.scrollTop` and `document.body.scrollLeft` at the end. But we don't know what you want, because you have not been clear about what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English.
im gonna try my exact problem here,
im working on iphone-UIWebView and i have a big html file.
this html file is loading to the UIWebView, but it paged by css because of this, has a horizontal scroll only. 
i have to find position on scroll a tag named like "Note". is it clear? :/

Comment: @relower In that case your original code works, or you could use `getBoundingClientRect()` and (as I said in my last comment) simply add in the value for `document.body.scrollLeft` (or whatever element has the scroll bar). Or perhaps you simply need the [`scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollIntoView) method.

Comment: How to get the full width and height of the document, including the scrolled out part?  --- I think that the question

Answer (score 7):

```
function position(elem) { 
    var left = 0, 
        top = 0; 

    do { 
        left += elem.offsetLeft-elem.scrollLeft; 
        top += elem.offsetTop-elem.scrollTop; 
    } while ( elem = elem.offsetParent ); 

    return [ left, top ]; 
} 
var elem = document.getElementById('id');
position(elem);

Subtract the scroll positions.
```

Comment: You should at least fix the code the OP pasted so that it's valid JavaScript. (Tip: look at the function argument.)

Comment: err, its returning negative result like "-280", how can i fix ?
also it seems to work, you may help me i think.

Answer (score 6):

Solution to find an element position for scroll:

```
const target = document.querySelector('[name="Note"]')
window.scrollTo({
    top: Math.round(target.getBoundingClientRect().top + document.documentElement.scrollTop),
    behavior: 'smooth',
})
```

Or just use `scrollIntoView`:

```
document.querySelector('[name="Note"]').scrollIntoView({
    behavior: 'smooth',
})
```

Answer (score 5):

My guess is that you need the note to stay fixed to the top left corner at all times? Even when scrolled?

You can do this with CSS only! :)

HTML:

```
<div id="Note" name="Note">Example</div>
```

CSS:

```
div #Note {
  background-color:rgb(255,255,204)
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 999;
}

@media screen {
  body > div #Note {
    position: fixed;
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**
With several notes (not tested):

HTML:

```
<div id="Note1">Example</div>
<div id="Note2">Example</div>
<div id="Note3">Example</div>
<div id="Note4">Example</div>
```

CSS:

```
div #Note1 {
  background-color:rgb(255,255,204)
  left: 0px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 999;
}
div #Note2 {
  background-color:rgb(255,255,204)
  left: 0px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 999;
}
div #Note3 {
  background-color:rgb(255,255,204)
  left: 0px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  z-index: 999;
}
div #Note4 {
  background-color:rgb(255,255,204)
  left: 0px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  z-index: 999;
}

@media screen {
  body > div #Note1 {
    position: fixed;
  }

  body > div #Note2 {
    position: fixed;
  }

  body > div #Note3 {
    position: fixed;
  }

  body > div #Note4 {
    position: fixed;
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the guess and suggestion, even if it doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: good solution, but what if there are lots of element named "Note" ? how can i make it worked for me ?

Comment: I edited the answer ...... I dont know if you manually or dynamically get your notes on the page, but there are several solutions on how to do it both way.. Just think creatively :)

Comment: Good answer bro, but its like a dream, because i dont know exact note count :) but i proud of you cause of your answer, really creative one, thanks :) this will be my last chance to solving the problem.

Comment: Well, are you getting the notes from a database, creating them dynamically with PHP or ASP? :)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to get the height of entire document. Height of the whole document, with the scrolled out part: [link](https://javascript.info/size-and-scroll-window)

```
let scrollHeight = Math.max(
    document.body.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight,
    document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight,
    document.body.clientHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight
);
```

After you can use to get element's scrollTop position:

```
const element = document.getElementsByName('Note');
element.scrollTop
```

Or you can go to element on view ([scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView))

I'm not sure what you want to do after get the scrollTop position.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
  <script>function showDiv() {

            var div = document.getElementById('comdiv');
            var button = document.getElementById('button');
            if (div.style.display !== "none") {
                div.style.display = "none";
                button.value = "Add Comments";

            }
            else {
                button.value = "Hide Comments";
                div.style.display = "block";
            }
            var note = document.getElementsByName("comment")[0];
            var screenPosition = note.getBoundingClientRect();
            window.scrollTo(screenPosition);
        }</script>
            <form name="form" id="form" action="" method="post">
            <textarea name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="Write Comment, Max: 140 characters" rows="4"  class="width-50" onblur="checkMe()" ></textarea>
            <input type="text" class="input-small width-33" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" autofocus class="width-33" onblur="checkMe()" />
            <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submitbutton" class="btn btn-green btn-outline" disabled="disabled">Post Comment</button>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In ANGULAR:

```js
import { ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
...
export class NewTrendingComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('theElementInQuestion') public trendyElement!: ElementRef;
  
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    // log the top pixel value of the element in question
    console.log(this.trendyElement.nativeElement.offsetTop)
  }
  
 }
```

```html
...

  <div #theElementInQuestion> this is the element you are looking for... </div>
  
  ...
```

> Note: if you are using structural directives like ngIf, you want to look into when exactly the element will render (usually with / after after ViewInit if | async). Or look into using the {static: true} option.

```
@ViewChild('theElementInQuestion', {static: true}) public trendyElement!: ElementRef;
```