# Check if scrolled past div with JavaScript (no jQuery)

Tags: javascript

I am currently learning JavaScript and all the solutions that I've come across use the jQuery library.  Is there a way to do it, just using pure JavaScript?

The idea is to have something like:

```
function passed(element) {if passed: do something}
```

Comment: I think you will find the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070639/find-elements-position-in-browser-scroll  In your specific case, when bottom is negative you have scrolled passed

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Listen for the `scroll` event. To find the current scroll position, you can call the `scollY` method.

To get the Y coordinate of the top of an element, you can use the element's `offsetTop`. Because the element has a height, we want to add the height to our calculation.

That's it.

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  var elementTarget = document.getElementById("section-2");
  if (window.scrollY > (elementTarget.offsetTop + elementTarget.offsetHeight)) {
      alert("You've scrolled past the second div");
  }
});
```

```css
.section-1 {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
}

.section-3 {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-1"></div>
<div id="section-2">Scroll past this div</div>
<div class="section-3"></div>
```

Comment: Please, take in mind that element coordinates are the coordinates of the left-upper corner. There is unfortunately no single property which gives absolute coordinates. Take a look at how to calculate it  --> http://javascript.info/tutorial/coordinates#element-coordinates-by-offsetparent

Comment: Any way to do this with multiple divs, for example, DIVs with the same class name?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use the following:

```
if(window.scrollY >(element.offsetHeight + element.offsetTop)){
    // do something 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if (element.getBoundingClientRect().y < 0) {
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop you can get the Y coordinate of an element.

With https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY you can get the current Y coordinate of the scroll.

With https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight you get the height of an element.

So the only thing that remains to do is to check if scrollY > (offsetHeight + offsetTop). If this is true, you passed the element with the scroll.

I leave to you the implementation, as a practice to learn Javascript ;)

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with the [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) API without having to rely on scroll events at all.

```js
const elementTarget = document.getElementById("section-2");

// skip first callback when first observing
let firstCallback = true;
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
  if (!entries[0].isIntersecting) {
     if (firstCallback) {
       firstCallback = false;
     } else {
       alert("You've scrolled past the second div");
     }
  }
});
observer.observe(elementTarget);
// remember to unobserve when done
```

```css
.section-1 {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
}

.section-3 {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-1"></div>
<div id="section-2">Scroll past this div</div>
<div class="section-3"></div>
```